# Why does linking with `mingw32` solve this compilation problem with SDL2?

Tags: c, windows, mingw, sdl

I'm learning development using SDL2 with C on Windows and Mingw.

I tried the following command to compile my program:

```
gcc -IC:C:/msys64_new/mingw64/include/SDL2 *.c -o game.exe -g -Wall -Wno-unused -LC:/msys64_new/mingw64/lib -lSDL2main -lSDL2
```

It gave the error: `Undefined reference to WinMain`

Then I read that I should add `-lmingw32` to the command:

```
gcc -IC:C:/msys64_new/mingw64/include/SDL2 *.c -o game.exe -g -Wall -Wno-unused -LC:/msys64_new/mingw64/lib -lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2
```

And now it works! My questions are:

1. Why does this solve the problem? What does linking with `libmingw32.a` do that solves this?
2. How does `gcc` find `libmingw32.a`? I don't seem to have such a file in the folder directed by `-LC:/msys64_new/mingw64/lib`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

libmingw32 is a part of mingw implementation of C runtime library, including e.g. [crt0](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crt0) and thread-local storage, stuff happening before your `main` is called. If you ask gcc to inform you what it does under the hood via `gcc -v the_rest_of_your_build_command` you'll see that it have `-lmingw32` anyway in its linking command; it is possible to drop CRT (and CRT0) but that's for another question (and you'll need special handling since ordinary C programs expect CRT to be present).

There are some predefined paths linker search for libraries in. Historically for unix-like systems there are `/lib`, `/usr/lib` and so on. As mingw is mostly just ported gcc toolchain it inherits the same paths, just with its installation directory prefix (e.g. `c:\mingw-w64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\lib`. Check outout of `ld --verbose` output, specifically `SEARCH_DIR`.

Now why you need to specify `-lmingw32` even though it is there anyway - the only reason is how ld linker resolves dependencies - left to right rule, basically. If one static library depends on another, it needs to be specified first in libraries list (but can be specified multiple times, it will not produce a conflict). In your case, `#include <SDL.h>` redefines your `main` function to `SDL_main`; that way your program don't have defined entry point anymore, but `libSDL2main.a` have one - simple `main` or `WinMain` that does minimal preparation and calls your `SDL_main`. So, you need to link with `-lSDL2main`, but by default `-lmingw32` is appended last (resulting in e.g. `-lSDL2main -lSDL2 -lmingw32`), and linker don't search for definition of `WinMain` in `SDL2main`, and there is no `WinMain` in your `.o`s, hence linking error. If you add `-lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2`, you have correct dependency chain - CRT0 depends on `WinMain` which implemented in `SDL2main` which also depends on `SDL2`. Default parameters will still add `-lmingw32` at the tail, so you'll implicitly have it twice, but as I've said before you're allowed to do so.

Comment: Interesting. I wonder why the linker does look for `main` in *object files* linked before `-lmingw32`, if it doesn't do it for libraries.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat sorry I don't know exact reason for that. I suspect object files have weaker rules because cross-object-file references are way too common and it would be insane to ask programmer to specify object files in dependency order too. Also contrary to library, you can't use object file twice in linking process, so some of dependency loops may be unsolvable.