# Where are the standard C I/O functions defined in MinGW?

Tags: c, windows, mingw, mingw-w64

I know that when using GCC, the standard I/O functions (e.g. `printf`, `fprintf`, etc.) are defined in the static library `libc.a`. However, I need to know where they are defined in the MinGW environment, which doesn't have a `libc.a`. Inside of my MinGW installation, I did find the following libraries: `libcap.a`, `libcfgmgr32.a`, `libcoldname.a`, `libcomctl32.a`, `libcomdlg32.a`, `libcrtdll.a`, `libcrypt32.a`, and `libctl3d32.a`. However, I have zero clue as to whether these relate to what I want.

In essence, I need to know where the standard C I/O  functions are defined in the MinGW environment.

---

As an update, these are all the libraries MinGW links by default: `libmingw32.a`, `libmoldname.a`, `libmingwex.a`, `libmsvcrt.a`, `libadvapi32.a`, `libshell32.a`, and `libuser32.a`. I'm thinking it might be (or be in some way connected to) one of these?

Comment: I'm guessing `libcrtdll.a`. "crt" probably stands for C Runtime Library.

Comment: I removed that library from the default MinGW lib directory, but a simple I/O program I wrote still seems to compile and run, so I don't think that's the one.

Comment: Its looking like it could be `libmingw32.a`, but I'm still figuring that one out.

Comment: Keltar's answer at this post seems promising: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60779478/why-does-linking-with-mingw32-solve-this-compilation-problem-with-sdl2

Answer (score 3):

This is more complicated than you might hope because there are several different ways a function can be defined in the MinGW environment:

1. As an inline function in a header file.
2. As a symbol in a static library file (i.e. `.a`).
3. As a symbol in an import library (`.a`) that imports a function with a similar name at run time from a DLL.  This DLL could be part of Windows or part of MinGW.

So let's suppose that `test.c` is a basic hello world program in C that calls `printf` from `main`.

Run `gcc -S test.c` and then `less test.s` to see the assembly GCC generates for this code.  If your MinGW setup is like mine (the MINGW64 environment in MSYS2), you will see that test.s actually includes the code for `printf`.  This tells us that `printf` is defined in a MinGW header somewhere.  If you look carefully at the assembly, you will see it basically just calls `__mingw_vfprintf`.

Now run `gcc test.c -g -o test -Wl,-Map=test.map` and `less test.map`.  Search for `__mingw_vfprintf`, to find out where it comes from.  In my case, it comes from `C:/msys64/mingw64/lib/libmingwex.a`.

You can try running `objdump -d /mingw64/lib/libmingwex.a` to see the compiled code of `__mingw_vfprintf` but it's not great: it doesn't seem to show the names of the three functions that `__mingw_vfprintf` calls.  Luckily, GDB can show us that.  You already compiled `test.exe` with the earlier command, so run `gdb ./test.exe` to start the debugger, and then run these commands in it:

```
break __mingw_vfprintf
run
layout asm
```

Note that the first command prints out the name of the source file (on the build server) for `__mingw_vfprintf`, which could be useful.

The final command shows us the assembly in `__mingw_vfprintf`, and we can see that it calls three functions.  The most interesting function it calls is `__mingw_pformat`.

Run `break __mingw_pformat` and `continue` to jump to that function.  There's lots of stuff going on in that function.  You could dig into it with the debugger or by looking at the source code to get more information.  It probably calls a function in `msvcrt.dll` or some other Windows DLL at some point.

Another way to tackle this is to look at what functions get imported from DLLs at runtime.  To do this, run `objdump -p test.exe | less` and look for "The Import Tables".  If your environment is like mine, you will see that `fprintf` and `vfprintf` and several other C I/O functions get imported at runtime from `msvcrt.dll`, which is part of Windows.  This is a very important DLL which is the foundation of the traditional MinGW environments, but you can configure MinGW in a variety of ways that let is use different foundations (i.e. newer versions of the DLL, or the UCRT).

Comment: I'll be honest, I'm not familiar with assembly. However, I compiled a program using my MinGW environment with the `-save-temps` flag and looked at the code inside of the `.i` file that is generated after the preprocessor runs (I believe?). In this, I found that the `fprintf` function was declared, but not defined (I didn't see any code for it). At least, that's what I think, but please correct me if my methods were wrong there (I wouldn't be surprised if they were).

Comment: OK, that might be valid in your environment.  I don't know how you configured MinGW or what preocompiled toolchain you downloaded.  For me, I see `fprintf` defined in `test.i` as a static inline function with about 5 lines of code in it, calling `__mingw_vfprintf`.

Comment: P.S. You don't really need to know assembly, just need to be able to scan it and discern x86 opcodes from function names, which you can mostly do based on their position, because the opcode comes at the start of the line.